# Wait for promise to complete

Tags: angular, angular-promise

I have read some posts regarding this subject but I have still not found the solution for this.

This my scenario:

I have a service: PermissionService, which looks like:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
hasPermission(operation: string, objects: string): Observable<Permission> {
    let queryStr: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    queryStr = queryStr.set(“operation”,operation);
    queryStr = queryStr.set(“objects”,objects);
    return this.http.get<Permission>(this.url + permissionType, { params: queryStr });
}
```

In my component I have injected the service and I use it like this:

```
hasCreatePermission(){  
        this.permissionsService.hasPermission("C","Categories").subscribe(
          res => {
              this.canCreate = res.data[0].result;
          }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (err.error instanceof Error) {
              console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
          } else {
            console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
        }
    });
}
```

When the promise finalizes the variable canCreate is set with the value of the permission.

This variable is used in my template to hide or show some component such as buttons.

All this stuff is working properly. So my question is.. is there any way in 
Angular to make it synchronous?

To be able to call the method like:

This.canCreate = this.servicePermission.hasPermission…. I do not contiune the executing until the promise is resolved so I can get the result before the template is rendered.

I need this because I cannot display a page with buttons that are going to disappear after some seconds due to the permissions.

I agree that some calls to the backend such as getting data from the server need to be async but in this case I need the result to be able to render the page appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to wait for it to resolve to be able to render your component that depends on what the resolved value is.

What you should do is use the [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) in your component markup, and conditionally render buttons etc.

Something like

`<button [hidden]="!canCreate | async">Click me if allowed!</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Http requests return Obseravbles, in order to not block the browser. If you want to delay the loading of your component/template consider using Resolvers in Angular. They are specially made for this scenario.

More on resolvers and prefetching 
https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data